# How to not let an object go beyond the canvas on JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a canvas on html and using JavaScript, I created an object (a square) that can be controlled using WASD keys.

```
var object = {
    height: 40,
    width: 40,
    x: 10,
    y: 10, 
    color: "black"      
}
```

I want it to stop when it hits any of the edges of canvas. Here's my keydown event. As far as I know, I think it's when a user presses any of the WASD keys should it stop, but I'm not particularly sure of the conditions to do so.

```
var nowKey= 0;
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if (nowKey== e.keyCode) return;
    nowKey= e.keyCode;
    
    //left
    if (e.keyCode == 65) {
        movX--;
    }
    //up
    else if (e.keyCode == 87) {
        movY--;
    }
    //right
    else if (e.keyCode == 68) {
        movX++;
    }
    //down
    else if (e.keyCode == 83) {
        movY++;
    }
});
```

Comment: You should stop at the top and left if the current value is 0 and at the right and bottom if the current value is the canvas size - 1

Comment: @ThomasSablik by current value, you meant the movX and movY, right?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I tried e.keyCode == 37 && movX != 0 for LEFT but the object won't move to the left anymore. Same goes with the top

Comment: Probably you did something wrong in the code you didn't post.